# OpenCV crashes after a short time in Android app

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, android, tegra

I have an app which performs some image stitching and uses OpenCV. It used to work but all of a sudden it crashes (randomly?) all of the time. I don't know why this happens, I didn't change the code, but also didn't try that feature for several weeks now. There was probably an Android update in the meantime on my Nvidia Shield.

It used to work with OpenCV 2.4.10, but since it didn't work with that version anymore, I've tried to switch to OpenCV 3.0.0 which shows the same behavior.

My setup:

- Nvidia Shield with Android 5.1.1
- Installed `OpenCV_3.0.0_manager_3.00_armeabi-v7a.apk` manager
- Build target is Android 5.1.1
- Integrated OpenCV 3.0 Library from the Android SDK into my Android project. Inside the SDK, this is the path to the library: `%path-to-sdk%/OpenCV3-android-sdk/sdk/java`

My application behaves like follows: It seems to successfully load and initialize OpenCV and even starts to capture and stitch together some images. After three or four images, it crashes. Here are the Android logs which are logged during the crash:

```
02-01 13:07:55.172: I/AudioFlinger(209): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST accepted: frameCount=11258 mFrameCount=512
02-01 13:07:55.321: E/Camera2-ZslProcessor3(209): pushToReprocess: Could not find good candidate for ZSL reprocessing
02-01 13:07:55.582: E/Error(209): configureSensor: cannot find a sensor mode for 2592x1944
02-01 13:07:56.391: W/Camera2-ZslProcessor3(209): getCandidateTimestampLocked: ZSL queue has no metadata frames
02-01 13:07:56.391: E/Camera2-ZslProcessor3(209): pushToReprocess: Could not find good candidate for ZSL reprocessing
02-01 13:07:56.653: E/Error(209): configureSensor: cannot find a sensor mode for 2592x1944
02-01 13:07:56.745: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.google.android.partnersetup (pid 22851) has died
02-01 13:07:57.301: W/Camera2-ZslProcessor3(209): getCandidateTimestampLocked: ZSL queue has no metadata frames
02-01 13:07:57.301: E/Camera2-ZslProcessor3(209): pushToReprocess: Could not find good candidate for ZSL reprocessing
02-01 13:07:57.640: E/Error(209): configureSensor: cannot find a sensor mode for 2592x1944
02-01 13:07:58.134: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.google.android.calendar (pid 23255) has died
02-01 13:07:58.139: E/lowmemorykiller(174): Error writing /proc/22747/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 13:07:58.146: I/BackgroundMemoryTrimmer(22823): Trimming objects from memory, since app is in the background.
02-01 13:07:58.173: I/PersonalGridService(22885): onTrimMemory called with level: 5
02-01 13:07:58.174: I/ActivityManager(632): Process android.process.acore (pid 22747) has died
02-01 13:07:58.271: W/Camera2-ZslProcessor3(209): getCandidateTimestampLocked: ZSL queue has no metadata frames
02-01 13:07:58.271: E/Camera2-ZslProcessor3(209): pushToReprocess: Could not find good candidate for ZSL reprocessing
02-01 13:07:58.322: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.android.providers.calendar (pid 23231) has died
02-01 13:07:58.364: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.google.android.apps.plus (pid 23125) has died
02-01 13:07:58.365: E/lowmemorykiller(174): Error writing /proc/23104/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 13:07:58.369: I/PersonalGridService(22885): onTrimMemory called with level: 10
02-01 13:07:58.381: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.android.chrome (pid 23104) has died
02-01 13:07:58.400: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.google.android.apps.photos (pid 23029) has died
02-01 13:07:58.407: I/PersonalGridService(22885): onTrimMemory called with level: 15
02-01 13:07:58.432: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.google.process.gapps (pid 22637) has died
02-01 13:07:58.433: E/lowmemorykiller(174): Error opening /proc/22823/oom_score_adj; errno=2
02-01 13:07:58.434: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search (pid 22823) has died
02-01 13:07:58.566: E/Error(209): configureSensor: cannot find a sensor mode for 2592x1944
02-01 13:07:58.608: I/ActivityManager(632): Process org.opencv.engine:OpenCVEngineProcess (pid 22529) has died
02-01 13:07:59.175: W/Camera2-ZslProcessor3(209): getCandidateTimestampLocked: ZSL queue has no metadata frames
02-01 13:07:59.175: E/Camera2-ZslProcessor3(209): pushToReprocess: Could not find good candidate for ZSL reprocessing
02-01 13:07:59.277: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.google.android.talk (pid 22787) has died
02-01 13:07:59.277: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.talk/com.google.android.libraries.hangouts.video.CallService in 1000ms
02-01 13:07:59.280: I/ActivityManager(632): Process android.process.media (pid 22454) has died
02-01 13:07:59.280: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.providers.media/.MtpService in 1000ms
02-01 13:07:59.291: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.nvidia.penapplauncher (pid 22972) has died
02-01 13:07:59.291: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.nvidia.penapplauncher/com.nvidia.quickMenu.QuickMenuService in 10988ms
02-01 13:07:59.365: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.nvidia.tegrazone3 (pid 22477) has died
02-01 13:07:59.365: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.nvidia.tegrazone3/com.nvidia.tegrazone.account.AccountService in 20915ms
02-01 13:07:59.365: E/lowmemorykiller(174): Error opening /proc/22616/oom_score_adj; errno=2
02-01 13:07:59.366: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.google.android.gms (pid 22616) has died
02-01 13:07:59.366: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService in 30914ms
02-01 13:07:59.441: E/Error(209): configureSensor: cannot find a sensor mode for 2592x1944
02-01 13:07:59.510: I/ActivityManager(632): Start proc 23500:com.nvidia.tegrazone3/u0a65 for service com.nvidia.tegrazone3/com.nvidia.tegrazone.account.AccountService
02-01 13:07:59.671: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.nvidia.tegrazone3:PersonalGridService (pid 22885) has died
02-01 13:07:59.671: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.nvidia.tegrazone3/com.nvidia.grid.PersonalGridService.pgService in 20609ms
02-01 13:07:59.966: W/Camera2-ZslProcessor3(209): getCandidateTimestampLocked: ZSL queue has no metadata frames
02-01 13:07:59.966: E/Camera2-ZslProcessor3(209): pushToReprocess: Could not find good candidate for ZSL reprocessing
02-01 13:08:00.020: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.google.android.inputmethod.latin (pid 22923) has died
02-01 13:08:00.020: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME in 30260ms
02-01 13:08:00.100: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.google.android.gms.persistent (pid 22659) has died
02-01 13:08:00.100: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.internal.PendingIntentCallbackService in 40180ms
02-01 13:08:00.100: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.common.stats.GmsCoreStatsService in 50180ms
02-01 13:08:00.100: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService in 60180ms
02-01 13:08:00.100: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.fused.FusedLocationService in 70180ms
02-01 13:08:00.100: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.deviceconnection.service.DeviceConnectionServiceBroker in 80180ms
02-01 13:08:00.100: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.network.NetworkLocationService in 90180ms
02-01 13:08:00.100: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.geofencer.service.GeofenceProviderService in 100180ms
02-01 13:08:00.100: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService in 110180ms
02-01 13:08:00.100: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.geocode.GeocodeService in 120180ms
02-01 13:08:00.100: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.internal.GoogleLocationManagerService in 130179ms
02-01 13:08:00.100: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.internal.server.GoogleLocationService in 140179ms
02-01 13:08:00.100: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.contextmanager.service.ContextManagerService in 150179ms
02-01 13:08:00.101: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.reporting.service.DispatchingService in 160179ms
02-01 13:08:00.116: I/WindowState(632): WIN DEATH: Window{1026bdfe u0 com.nvidia.ControllerMapper}
02-01 13:08:00.341: E/Surface(209): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
02-01 13:08:00.343: W/InputDispatcher(632): channel '3438de7d mobileBRDF.Renderer/mobileBRDF.ImageProcessing.ImageProcessingActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
02-01 13:08:00.343: E/InputDispatcher(632): channel '3438de7d mobileBRDF.Renderer/mobileBRDF.ImageProcessing.ImageProcessingActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-01 13:08:00.378: W/CameraService(209): Disconnecting camera client 0xae447290 since the binder for it died (this pid 209)
02-01 13:08:00.379: E/Camera3-OutputStream(209): returnBufferCheckedLocked: Stream 0: Error queueing buffer to native window: Broken pipe (-32)
02-01 13:08:00.379: E/Camera3-Device(209): Can't return buffer to its stream: Broken pipe (-32)
02-01 13:08:00.379: E/Camera3-OutputStream(209): getBufferLocked: Stream 0: Can't dequeue next output buffer: Broken pipe (-32)
02-01 13:08:00.379: E/Camera3-Device(209): RequestThread: Can't get output buffer, skipping request: Broken pipe (-32)
02-01 13:08:00.379: E/Camera2ClientBase(209): Error condition 3 reported by HAL, requestId 30000005
02-01 13:08:00.383: W/InputDispatcher(632): channel '24b71005 mobileBRDF.Renderer/mobileBRDF.HDR.EnvMapCaptureActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
02-01 13:08:00.383: E/InputDispatcher(632): channel '24b71005 mobileBRDF.Renderer/mobileBRDF.HDR.EnvMapCaptureActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-01 13:08:00.396: E/Surface(209): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
02-01 13:08:00.396: E/Camera3-OutputStream(209): returnBufferCheckedLocked: Stream 0: Error queueing buffer to native window: Broken pipe (-32)
02-01 13:08:00.396: E/Camera3-Device(209): Can't return buffer to its stream: Broken pipe (-32)
02-01 13:08:00.415: E/Surface(209): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
02-01 13:08:00.415: E/Camera3-OutputStream(209): returnBufferCheckedLocked: Stream 0: Error queueing buffer to native window: Broken pipe (-32)
02-01 13:08:00.415: E/Camera3-Device(209): Can't return buffer to its stream: Broken pipe (-32)
02-01 13:08:00.431: E/Surface(209): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
02-01 13:08:00.431: E/Camera3-OutputStream(209): returnBufferCheckedLocked: Stream 0: Error queueing buffer to native window: Broken pipe (-32)
02-01 13:08:00.431: E/Camera3-Device(209): Can't return buffer to its stream: Broken pipe (-32)
02-01 13:08:00.518: E/Surface(209): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
02-01 13:08:00.518: E/Camera3-OutputStream(209): returnBufferCheckedLocked: Stream 0: Error queueing buffer to native window: Broken pipe (-32)
02-01 13:08:00.518: E/Camera3-Device(209): Can't return buffer to its stream: Broken pipe (-32)
02-01 13:08:00.571: E/Surface(209): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
02-01 13:08:00.571: E/Camera3-OutputStream(209): returnBufferCheckedLocked: Stream 0: Error queueing buffer to native window: Broken pipe (-32)
02-01 13:08:00.571: E/Camera3-Device(209): Can't return buffer to its stream: Broken pipe (-32)
02-01 13:08:00.610: I/WindowState(632): WIN DEATH: Window{2fbeaa8b u0 SurfaceView}
02-01 13:08:00.844: I/WindowState(632): WIN DEATH: Window{24b71005 u0 mobileBRDF.Renderer/mobileBRDF.HDR.EnvMapCaptureActivity}
02-01 13:08:00.844: W/InputDispatcher(632): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '24b71005 mobileBRDF.Renderer/mobileBRDF.HDR.EnvMapCaptureActivity (server)'
02-01 13:08:00.912: I/WindowState(632): WIN DEATH: Window{3438de7d u0 mobileBRDF.Renderer/mobileBRDF.ImageProcessing.ImageProcessingActivity}
02-01 13:08:00.912: W/InputDispatcher(632): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '3438de7d mobileBRDF.Renderer/mobileBRDF.ImageProcessing.ImageProcessingActivity (server)'
02-01 13:08:00.912: W/WindowManager(632): Force-removing child win Window{d2dcab1 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{3438de7d u0 mobileBRDF.Renderer/mobileBRDF.ImageProcessing.ImageProcessingActivity}
02-01 13:08:00.953: W/WindowManager(632): Failed looking up window
02-01 13:08:00.953: W/WindowManager(632): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@821958 does not exist
02-01 13:08:00.953: W/WindowManager(632):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8559)
02-01 13:08:00.953: W/WindowManager(632):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8550)
02-01 13:08:00.953: W/WindowManager(632):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1142)
02-01 13:08:00.953: W/WindowManager(632):   at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:551)
02-01 13:08:00.953: I/WindowState(632): WIN DEATH: null
02-01 13:08:00.955: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:interactor (pid 23335) has died
02-01 13:08:00.955: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.voiceinteraction.GsaVoiceInteractionService in 942128ms
02-01 13:08:00.956: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.nvidia.ControllerMapper (pid 22589) has died
02-01 13:08:00.956: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.nvidia.ControllerMapper/.MapperService in 159324ms
02-01 13:08:00.957: I/ActivityManager(632): Process com.nvidia.stats (pid 22508) has died
02-01 13:08:00.957: W/ActivityManager(632): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.nvidia.stats/.StatsService in 169323ms
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632): Session failed to close due to remote exception
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632): android.os.DeadObjectException
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:305)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1420)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearClientSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1411)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1437)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:1456)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1213)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1227)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:269)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:170)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
02-01 13:08:00.983: W/InputMethodManagerService(632):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
02-01 13:08:00.998: I/stats(632): onServiceDisconnected
02-01 13:08:00.998: I/stats(632): onServiceDisconnected
02-01 13:08:01.054: I/ActivityManager(632): Start proc 23521:android.process.media/u0a5 for service com.android.providers.media/.MtpService
02-01 13:08:01.057: I/ActivityManager(632): Process mobileBRDF.Renderer (pid 22471) has died
02-01 13:08:01.058: W/ActivityManager(632): Force removing ActivityRecord{1e7f649b u0 mobileBRDF.Renderer/mobileBRDF.HDR.EnvMapCaptureActivity t1990}: app died, no saved state
```

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Could it be that I've missed something during configuration? (something regarding the OpenCV manager maybe?)

Any ideas what I could do to narrow down the error?

**Update:**

I still haven't been able to figure out the problem on the Nvidia Shield. It just crashes somewhere inside OpenCV. Tested on 2 different Nvidia Shield devices => crashes on both. The same build + the same config runs without crashing on the Google Nexus 9 which has the same GPU (Nvidia K1). Crazy times!